# Karate testing UI : what is syntax entering random value in text field

Tags: karate

I am trying to enter a random string in text box using the input(“X-path”,’#(name)’). Script is failing with invalid syntax .
Can anyone  help me with the correct syntax

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working sample script created for POC

- Feature: create order

  Background

  - def now=function(){return java.lang.System.currentTimeMills()}
    *def ordername='order'+now()

  Scenario: Create random order
- Given call read('login.feature')
- Given driver 'url to navigate to another page'
- And click('#selector')
- And input("x-path",ordername)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the fact that variables can be used "as is" in JS functions.

```
* def name = 'foo'
* input('/some/path', name)
```

The `'#(name)'` syntax is *only* for JSON: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: Thank you Peter for answering the question.